# How to automate jpg creation for all colors?

Tags: color, automation

I need to get each  hexadecimal color in jpgs (or another format). I don't know if this is possible in PS by automating the process somehow, but ideally I'd like to create the image in let's say #ffffff and have the computer go through all the colors and create a jpg for each file.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Off hand I'd say it would require scripting. I've done something similar with PHP, so it's just a matter of "walking" the values really.

Answer (score 0):

This is done pretty easily with ImageMagick's [primitive draw](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#primitives) command.

The following command should output a 100px x 100px red image.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:white -fill "rgb(255,0,0)" \
        -draw "rectangle 0,0 100,100" FF0000.jpg
```

Use whatever command line scripting you're familiar with to automate this and loop it over all 16.7 million possible RGB colors. The variables changed with each iteration would be your color within `rgb()` and the filename at the end.

Comment: Thanks!
I was looking at imagemagick but initially focused on Photoshop.
I'll see if I can also encode exif data into the image somehow.
Thanks.